# Could not locate module - jest with esm nodejs app

Tags: node.js, express, es6-modules, ts-jest

I'm trying to write tests for my express endpoints, but I'm having troubles importing express with jest.

My `package.json` has `"type": "module",` set and my tsconfig looks as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2020",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I have to import files providing the `.js` extension, otherwise the console yells at me that modules cannot be found, eg.

```
import {validateToken} from "../registration/validate.js";
```

It breaks jest of course, so I use `moduleNameMapper`. Here is my jest config:

```
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/src/test.setup.ts"
    ],
    "testRegex": "src/.*\\.test\\.(t|j)sx?$",
    "transform": {
      "\\.[jt]sx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "useESM": true
      }
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "(.+)\\.js": "$1"
    },
    "extensionsToTreatAsEsm": [
      ".ts"
    ]
  }
```

Unfortunately it results in broken imports for `express` dependencies:

```
    Configuration error:
    
    Could not locate module ipaddr.js mapped as:
    $1.
    
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/(.+)\.js/": "$1"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }

    > 1 | import express from "express";
        | ^
      2 | import cors from "cors";
      3 | import dotenv from "dotenv";
      4 | import {Server, createServer} from "http";

      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:759:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/proxy-addr/index.js:24:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/express/lib/utils.js:22:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:24:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/express/lib/express.js:18:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/express/index.js:11:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app.ts:1:1)
```

Comment: Typically you'd check if it was a _relative_ import, i.e. starts with a `.`, in your `moduleNameMapper`, so you can distinguish between the imports that need to be rewritten with `.js` and those that are coming from `node_modules`.

Comment: "It breaks jest of course" no it doesn't. But: Jest works with typescript by running its own babel conversion, which you almost _certainly_ don't want. What you want instead is for Jest to just use _your_ JS by pointing it at your build dir, not your src dir, and running a build as first step in running your test suite.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the idea was pretty cool, but unfortunately it iterates through the whole `node_modules` directory and affects module's relative imports as well. I wonder if there's a way to prevent `moduleNameMapper` from influencing `node_modules`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans when I point to my built files, it yells at me, saying:

dist/app.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import express from "express";
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Indeed, you'll need to explicitly force the vm into module mode using the runtime flag as you discovered - not the easiest to find, but this is noted in https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9430. _Technically_ Jest does not have ESM support right now, because the way it works for CJS can't work for modules while Node and V8 still have a bunch of unresolved bugs relating to the things Jest needs to do.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I finally figured it out. It may not be perfect but it works.
@Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans was right, but there was a missing part:

1. The test command should look like this `"test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"`
2. The `transform` prop needed a little adjustment

```js
"transform": {
  "\\.[jt]sx?$": [
    "ts-jest",
    {
      "useESM": true <<< here
    }
  ]
},
```

The rest is all about pointing jest to built files, instead of letting it to compile them by itself